# When I do a delete:TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

[table http://1.z9ls.com/t6/701/1555244797x1822611239.png](http://1.z9ls.com/t6/701/1555244797x1822611239.png)
one table is article,the other is category:
article:article_id,article_title,article_category_id...and article_category_id
is the foreign key and references category_id of table category.

When I **delete** an article：`object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.wjh.blog.domain.Category`
Attention:when I DELETE a article，but not insert or update.

```java
//I have already use the @Transactional 
//this is the code of ArticleDaoImpl.java
 @Override
    public void delete(Long article_id) {
        Article article = new Article();
        article.setArticle_id(article_id);
        this.getHibernateTemplate().delete(article);
    }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.wjh.blog.domain.Category" table="category">
        <id name="category_id" column="category_id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="category_name" column="category_name"/>
        <property name="category_parent_id" column="category_parent_id"/>
        <set name="category_articles" inverse="true">
            <key column="article_category_id"></key>
            <one-to-many class="com.wjh.blog.domain.Article"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.wjh.blog.domain.Article" table="article" >
        <id name="article_id" column="article_id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="article_title" column="article_title"/>
        <property name="article_content" column="article_content"/>
        <property name="article_time" column="article_time"/>
        <property name="article_pic" column="article_pic"/>
        <property name="article_desc" column="article_desc"/>
        <!--category-->
        <many-to-one name="article_category" class="com.wjh.blog.domain.Category"
                     column="article_category_id" cascade="save-update,persist" ></many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: can you add the complete entities of article and article category?

Comment: ```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Article {
    private Long article_id;
    private String article_title;
    private String article_content;
    private String article_time;
    private String article_pic;
    private String article_desc;
    private Long article_category_id;
    private Category article_category = new Category();
}
---
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Category {
    private Long category_id;
    private String category_name;
    private Long category_parent_id;
    private Set<Article> category_articles=new HashSet();
}
```

Comment: Article.java：
https://photos.google.com/album/AF1QipPkiVaYQIfOulEDWxiL-bdkZMWuYTA_LRoxbrT9/photo/AF1QipO8XbzjCR_Lnn8nlVySnEknIrmOPtxzMVeMqc3Q

---
Category.java：https://photos.google.com/album/AF1QipPkiVaYQIfOulEDWxiL-bdkZMWuYTA_LRoxbrT9/photo/AF1QipONKOoULmewA83c6fL43rJd-zpMUauxvQEzAbAn

---

tables of article and category:
https://photos.google.com/album/AF1QipPkiVaYQIfOulEDWxiL-bdkZMWuYTA_LRoxbrT9/photo/AF1QipOBEqS_3y5jgI2B8ygf5lzACWXQ0FsezxvCweTx

Comment: Not here in the example